# How to run Laravel queue commands on shared hosting?

Tags: laravel-5, cron, pusher-js

I have made a notifications system in my laravel project.
in development mode it works perfectly, but on shared hosting it doesn't because i couldn't run queue:listen to proccess the queued notifications.

Right now i use 000webhost free account to test my application and i could not find a way to run "php artisan queue:listen", i tried to create a "cron job" but it seems i don't know how to implement it because the way to create cron job on 000webhost is slightly different from the others, samething with laravel taks scheduling.

I use Pusher-js and laravel-echo to broadcast the notifications.
I read a lot of topics but could not find a clear solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need terminal access or some means of pushing a supervisor configuration or similar to the server, as well as restarting the service. I don't think you're going to have any luck on the free account though.

> 4) Users can access to server terminal (linux environment) via SSH,
>   which is not allowed for free accounts. If you upgrade to a premium
>   account, it is possible.

https://www.000webhost.com/forum/t/basic-question-mysql-with-php/28028/3